# How Do we recall PickView's didSelectRow after choosing a segment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I have used a segmented control for the user to choose between two type of results after they select a row in the pickerview. However, when I choose a row in the pickerview then it shows the result of selected segment, but I select another segment it doesn't do anything until I reselect the row again.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

i=row;
switch (i) {
    case 0:


case 1
if(_segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){

        [self Fquarter];
        [self Tquarter];
        [self Ten];
        [self Twenty];
        [self Fourty];
        [self Fifty];


        NSLog(@"AUDIO 10 MINS");
        }

        if(_segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){

            [self SFquarter];
            [self STquarter];
            [self STen];
            [self STwenty];
            [self SFourty];
            [self SFifty];

             NSLog(@"Visual 10 MINS");
        }
```

and it's like that for every case, what did I miss?

Comment: Of course that's what would happen. pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent: is only called when you change the row selection in the picker. It's not going to be called again when you select another segment in your segmented control. Also, what are you doing with the "case 1" line? You can't use that without being inside a switch statement.

Comment: @rdelmar I'm inside a switch, I'm only showing part my code but I've just edited my Q to show that. So, what are you suggesting? how do I recall didSelectRow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to call a method that has all the [self Fquarter], etc. statements from both the picker delegate method, and the action method for the segmented control. Something like this (pickerSelectedRow is a property typed as NSInteger):

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segment;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger pickerSelectedRow;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    self.pickerSelectedRow = row;
    [self doStuff];

}

-(IBAction)segmentChosen:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    [self doStuff];
}


-(void)doStuff {
    switch (self.pickerSelectedRow) {
        case 0:

        case 1:
            if(_segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){

                [self Fquarter];
                [self Tquarter];
                [self Ten];
                [self Twenty];
                [self Fourty];
                [self Fifty];


                NSLog(@"AUDIO 10 MINS");
            }

            if(_segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){

                [self SFquarter];
                [self STquarter];
                [self STen];
                [self STwenty];
                [self SFourty];
                [self SFifty];

                NSLog(@"Visual 10 MINS");
            }


    }
}
```

With this type of arrangement, the method where you set your values is called either when the picker view value changes or the segmented control's value changes.

Comment: Thank you! so, should I declare in .h like that? `@property (readwrite,nonatomic) NSInteger pickerSelectedRow;`

Comment: @user1949873, that should be ok, I usually just do nonatomic for integers. Also, unless you need to access this from other classes, it should go in the class extension at the top of the .m file, rather than in the .h.

Comment: I don't think I have declared it in the right way. Would you please add it to your answer?

Comment: @user1949873, I've edited my answer to show the whole .m file

Comment: Thank you very much, you're such a life saver